# Add Webmidi as global to my p5.js typescript project

Tags: typescript, p5.js, midi, web-midi

I'm building a p5.js sketch without any framework/bundler. I just have a sketch.ts file, provided in [this](https://github.com/Gaweph/p5-typescript-starter) p5-typescript-starter project.

I see that they do some declarations and fancy typescript stuff in the `global.d.ts` file that enables me to use all the types and classes for p5 in my `sketch.ts` file.

```js
//global.d.ts 
//works!
import * as p5Global from 'p5/global' 
import module = require('p5');
export = module;
export as namespace p5;
```

I want to have this same functionality, but for the `WebMidi` class (see https://webmidijs.org/), so I can access it my sketch.ts file. So I tried following the pattern used for exporting p5:

```
//webmidi.d.ts
//does not work as expected!
import * as webMidiGlobal from "webmidi"
import module = require('webmidi').WebMidi;

export = module;
export as namespace WebMidi
```

But when I go to try and use WebMidi, like I would p5, it doesn't work, I'm not getting intellisence and ts is throwing errors. For example, I know `WebMidi.enable()` is a valid function, but here we can see this is not recognized in VSCode:

[image]

What's the proper way to get WebMidi working with typescript, then?

TsConfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "none",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outFile": "./build/build.js",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "rootDir": "./sketch/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom"],
  }
}
```